# How to overlay audio over one another?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, motion-detection

Hello I am building an app which plays a sound when the user shakes it. Here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#define accelerationThreshold  0.5

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CMMotionManager *motionManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController
AVAudioPlayer *myAudio;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"sound"
                                     ofType:@"wav"]];

NSError *error;
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                initWithContentsOfURL:url
                error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}

////
_motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
_motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.5;

[_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue: [NSOperationQueue currentQueue]  withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
{
    [self motionMethod:motion];
}];

}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:@"sound"
                                     ofType:@"wav"]];

NSError *error;
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                initWithContentsOfURL:url
                error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",
          [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
}

////
_motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
_motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.5;

[_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue: [NSOperationQueue currentQueue]  withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
{
    [self motionMethod:motion];
}];

}

- (IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
[_audioPlayer play];
}

-(void)motionMethod:(CMDeviceMotion *)deviceMotion
{
CMAcceleration userAcceleration = deviceMotion.userAcceleration;
if (fabs(userAcceleration.x) > accelerationThreshold
    || fabs(userAcceleration.y) > accelerationThreshold
    || fabs(userAcceleration.z) > accelerationThreshold)
{
    //Motion detected, handle it with method calls or additional
    //logic here.
    [self playAudio:self];
}
}
```

However I want the sound to overlay the current sound every time a user shakes their device, how do I do this? Because currently it play eery time the sound finishes, how do I fix?

Comment: Bumping this up please help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not even looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To play more than one sound simultaneously with AVAudioPlayer, you need more than one AVAudioPlayer. You've only got one, so every time you send it `play` it is still the only one playing.

Comment: How do I detect if the audio is currently playing, I want to make an     if statement

Comment: Haha how? PLease tell!